# Error message "To accomplish this action, set property AssemblyName"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, smo

I am trying to generate script for all stored procedure in my database but it's throwing the following exception:

> To accomplish this action, set property AssemblyName.

Here is my code

```
Server myServer = new Server("SHAIWAL-PC");
Scripter scripter = new Scripter(myServer);
Database myAdventureWorks = myServer.Databases["MyDataBase"];
Urn[] DatabaseURNs = new Urn[] { myAdventureWorks.Urn };

StringCollection scriptCollection = scripter.Script(DatabaseURNs);
string Script = string.Empty;
ScriptingOptions scriptOptions = new ScriptingOptions();
foreach (StoredProcedure mysp in myAdventureWorks.StoredProcedures)
{
    StringCollection spscript = mysp.Script(scriptOptions);

    spscript = mysp.Script();
    foreach (string script in spscript)
    {
        Script += script;
        Script += "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Please help someone

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception? What is the stack trace?

Comment: This line throws the exception    StringCollection spscript = mysp.Script(scriptOptions);

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there any resolution?